# How to Send Data to a handler with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ajax, vb.net

Hello I am currently using a handler to run a stored procedure

i would like to send data to it but i am having trouble

I would like to make sure the code sends the data so the SP can use it as parameters

below is how i have tried before

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "CurvedJSON.ashx",
            type: "POST",
            data: "StoredProcedure&" + FirstName + 


        });
```

Comment: Did you mean: Sending a post data as parameter to CurvedJSON.ashx and get a return, a fetched data from CurvedJSON.ashx? Please give full detail of what you are really trying to solve

Comment: Apologies Stanley, i intent to post it, the pages function is a quote request form for a product, i intend for the user to fill out the form and request. On click i would like to send the data collected in the form to my SQL table via the Handler, the parameters for the stored procedure will come from the data form.. I don't need anything returned, just the data entered into the database

Comment: Can you share a link to an example of what you mean? Because I'm finding it so difficult to understand.

Comment: For example: `<form>[your name]---[email address]---[phone Number]------(Submit)</form>`.... Now when the user fill in the form, and click on the submit button, you want the data entered in the form to be initialized and sent to 'CurvedJSON.ashx' right?

Comment: Spot on ! the JSON will then run the SP and insert into the table

Comment: "Spot on" means yes? apologies if i ask so much questions, I just need to be sure of what to answer on!

Comment: yes, sorry, you've got it correct

Comment: You need to have jquery plugin attached into your <header>...</header>.... If you don't have, try this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: use the code below on Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it. Just play around with the code below!

**HTML**

```
    <form  id="form1" method="get" action="/CurvedJSON.ashx">
            <label>Name of Organization</label>
            <input type="text" name="OrgName" id="OrgName" class="textfield">
            <label>Address of Organization</label>
            <input type="text" name="OrgAddress" id="OrgAddress" class="textfield">
            <input type="submit" value="Register Organization">
        </form>
        <div id="response">Submit status will appear here.</div>
    
    <script>
    $document.ready(function(){
        $("#form1").submit(function(event){
           //When send the form, the code below prevents the page from redirecting the users
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            //Send the form to the server
            $.ajax({
                    url:'/CurvedJSON.ashx',
                    type:'POST',
            //get the data from the form and serialize it to JSON
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success:function(result){
            // if form is sent, send a feedback response like Done or successfully sent
                        $("#response").text("Successfully sent to the database");
    
                    },
                    error: function(){
                  //IF error occurred 
                        $("#response").text("Failed sending data");
                  }
                    
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Hope it help fix your problem?

Comment: You sir are amazing, is there anyway i can thank you ?

Comment: Yes: just click the correct check mark on the answer and rate the answer 1 vote up, so it will be useful to others in the future!